# Чем out отличается от ref?

Tags: c#

Функция с параметром с ключевым словом `out` даёт такой же результат, как и с `ref`.

Такой код:

```
private void func(out string value)
{
    value = "Hello World!";
}
```

Даёт такой же эффект, как и

```
private void func(ref string value)
{
    value = "Hello World!";
}
```

В чём же разница между `out` и `ref`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Разница в том, что `out` — это выходной параметр, а `ref` — входно-выходной.

Для `ref`-параметра вы должны передать его инициализированным, и можете пользоваться его исходным значением. А для `out`-параметра вы не обязаны инициализировать его перед вызовом функции, не можете использовать его значение в функции до присваивания, и обязаны инициализировать его в функции.

(Таким образом, `ref`-параметр немного напоминает *инициализированную* локальную переменную, а `out`-параметр — *неинициализированную*.)

Иллюстрация:

```
private void func1(out string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value); // нельзя, value не инициализировано
    if (false)
        return;               // нельзя, забыли установить значение value
    value = "Hello World!";
}

string s1;
func1(out s1);
```

```
private void func2(ref string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value); // можно
    if (false)
        return;               // не проблема, у value остаётся старое значение
    value = "Hello World!";
}

string s2;
func2(ref s2); // нельзя, функция имеет право использовать значение,
               // значит, оно должно быть инициализировано сначала
```

Таким образом, `out`-параметр — это как бы дополнительное возвращаемое значение функции. А `ref`-параметр — просто параметр, изменения которого видны снаружи функции.

---

На уровне CLR для `out`- и `ref`-параметров используется один и тот же механизм, но это незначительная техническая подробность. Разница в семантике.