# Метод в C#, меняющий местами значения переменных

Tags: c#, алгоритм, методы

Я новичок в программировании на C#, попался вопрос про обмен значениями переменных без использования третьей. С одним из решений все понятно:

```
int a = 2; 
int b = 4;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

У меня другой вопрос, можно ли это как-то засунуть в метод? Написал так:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Введите значения переменных a и b");
        Console.Write("a = ");

        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("b = ");

        int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        SwapNumbers(x, y);
        Console.Write($"Переменная a = {x}, переменная b = {y} ");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    public static void SwapNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
    }            
}
```

Но переменные x и y не меняются местами, по крайне мере в методе Main. Можно сделать так:

```
public static void SwapNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
        Console.Write($"Переменная a = {a}, переменная b = {b} ");
    }
```

Но это выглядит как-то коряво и неуместно, потому что я хочу, чтобы метод только менял местами введенные с клавиатуры значения, а где и когда их вывести я хочу решать сам.

Comment: Вы забыли указать параметрам модификатор `ref`, поэтому они передаются по значению и на переменные вне метода никакого влияния не оказывают

Comment: Ну и в современных версиях языка можно писать просто: `(x, y) = (y, x);`

Comment: @АндрейNOP насколько я знаю, в шарпе только через лямбду такое можно делать, простое приравнивание кортежей не пройдет

Comment: @kot_mapku3, я бы не писал, если б не был уверен или не проверил :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP а на rexter не работает, выдаёт ошибку. Это в какой версии добавили?

Comment: @kot_mapku3: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863142/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP а, окей:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что ты передаешь копии переменных в метод `Swap`. Чтобы иметь возможность передавать ссылку есть ключевое слово `ref`.

Т.е. метод будет выглядеть так:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 7, b = 5;
    Console.WriteLine("a -> {0}; b -> {1}", a, b);
    Swap(ref a, ref b);
    Console.WriteLine("a -> {0}; b -> {1}", a, b);
}

public static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b;
}
```

Есть также параметр out. Разница между ref и out тут: [ref и out](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480130/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-out-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-ref)

Comment: А что значит передаю копии? То есть я как бы даю значения этих переменных методу SwapNumbers, в методе Main они остаются те же, а метод SwapNumbers при этом не возвращает измененные значения?

Comment: @AlexVause, верно. Некоторые типы данных являются ссылочными, а некоторые типами значения. Например, int и char типы-значения, т.е. при передаче в метод или куда-то ещё передается именно то, что в переменной хранится. А вот ссылочные типы (например, класс) это типы, у которых берется не значение, а именно адрес места в памяти(как адрес улицы на которой вы живете. Могут прийти к вам по адресу и поселиться жить у вас, вместо покупки своего дома).

Answer (score 12):

Если использовать крайнюю версию языка C#, то можно вытворять [вот такой беспредел](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct#deconstructing-a-tuple)

```
int a = 10; 
int b = 15;

Console.WriteLine($"{a}-{b}");

(a, b) = (b, a); // обмен

Console.WriteLine($"{a}-{b}");
```

вывод ожидаемо

```
10-15
15-10
```

Answer (score 3):

При передаче в метод по значению (по умолчанию) в метод передается копия переменной, соответственно в вашем коде значения `x` и `y` не изменяются.

При указании модификатора `ref` переменные передаются в метод по ссылке, а не по значению. В этом случае при изменении значений переменной в методе будет изменено значение и в вызывающем методе.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b){
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    //Здесь <T> означает что будут использоваться неконкретные типы и мы эти типы и 
    //будем менять местами. При вызове метода нужно использовать такой синтаксис
    //int a = 0, b = 1;
    //Swap(ref a,ref b)
}
```

Можно в острые скобки (не знаю как их принято называть) вписываем тип переменной и всё.

Comment: "попался вопрос про обмен значениями переменных без использования **третьей**." И в методе `Main` у вас всё равно будут старые значения для `x` и `y`.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать третью. Ладно извините за невнимательность мой косяк.

Comment: На самом деле не особо важен сам алгоритм. В данный момент я разбираюсь с темами методов и областями видимости, поэтому просто хотелось понять, как приложить конкретный метод к введенным значениям.

Comment: `Swap<int>(ref a, ref b)` - `<int>`, можно опустить, так как тип известен компилятору, исходя из типов `a` и `b`